# Putting PC into Sleep causes all games to run poorly

Tags: windows-7, sleep, nvidia-graphics-card

After putting my PC to sleep and waking it back up, Games that normally run very smooth, Run very poorly, choppy, and almost unplayable.

I'm currently running on an ASUS Nvidia GTX 770. Current Drivers are 344.75 and are up to date. Intel I5-4690 @ 8 GB of Ram (DDR3). Win 7 64 Bit.

The only way I can get the computer back to it's normal performance, is to completely shut down and boot the system back up.

Anyone know what's the situation here? Or ran into this problem? Or how to fix the problem?

Comment: My laptop slow down after boot up from hibernation, so I usually just reboot my computer. If you dont have to save your windows section, just shut down after each time you use it.

Comment: Does the problem persist long after waking up (rule out slow/delayed components of wakeup)?  Can you tell from Task Manager or other status report whether any processes that are normally there are missing or stopped after wakeup?

Comment: There are different forms of hibernation/suspend. Eeach behaves differently, and there may be one that works somewhat correct. For example, there's something called hybrid standby, which is like hibernation, but using the standby feature. Then you have regular standby, but by using S3 Standby instructions through the bios, rather than S1, which makes the computer save everything to memory, then only putting little power on the memory circuits and putting the pc off. (no fans etc)

Comment: @fixer1234 > It happens until I reboot, Task Manger is clean of Unexpected CPU usage, I dont know what's missing if there is anything missing. LPChip I only use Sleep.

Comment: When the computer is running normally, make a list of the processes showing in Task Manager (sort alphabetically and grab screen shots).  After waking from sleep and experiencing the problem, open Task Manager and compare to the list.  If you don't spot anything missing, do the same with the services tab and look for services that show as stopped that are normally active.

Comment: Try different StandBy options. Also try disabling hybrid standby (which is likely to be used at the moment, and not working properly)

Comment: I would guess that your graphics support is switching modes.

Comment: ^ yea Is this GPU specific? like would a furmark test which is little cpu and a lot of gpu render be very slow? Could you check your "lanes width" to the GPU use CPU-Z in the mainboard section, or GPU-Z .   Newer motherboards have a super sleep mode for the PCI(&E) bus, could be switching that off in the bios/uefi might help? its like r6 sleep or something? Then check windows Advanced power properties, and make sure "system cooling policy" is in active mode not passive. and check the cpu "frequency" not just cpu use in resource monitor. Check also clock rate for the GPU. That's a start :-)